# Finding pairwise distances between all coordinate points, filtering distances with collinear points

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, geometry

I'm looking for help with a workflow that, given an arbitrary number of points in a (x, y) plane, can find all line segments that connect 2 (and only 2) points.  My first thought is to use `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist()` to get all unique pairwise distances, then for each distance between two points, test whether any of the other points are collinear.  I can imagine that approach becoming inefficient with large numbers of points, so I want to know if anyone knows of a more efficient way to solve this problem.

The question is unwieldy, so I'll provide an example.  I have a list of 3 (x, y) coordinate points `coords = [(1,1), (2,1), (3,1)]` that happen to form a straight line, and want to find the lengths of all line segments that connect 2 (and only 2) points.  For this example, I only have two line segments of length 1 that meet my criteria (from `(1,1)` to `(2,1)`, and `(2,1)` to `(3,1)`).  I can get all the pairwise distances between points using `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist()`, but that function's result includes the distance between `(1,1)` and `(3,1)`, which I don't want.

My preferred language is Python, but I'm open to answers in other coding languages.

Comment: If I understand correct, you want the distance for all pairs, that are neighbors in a list? Or is there something else to it?

Comment: @user3184950 You could put it that way, yes.  I didn't phrase it that way because "neighbors" typically assumes near neighbors, which wasn't my intention.  You could see it as identifying neighboring points, so long as a line between those two points doesn't intersect a third point.

Comment: I am still unclear if there is any difference if 10 points are on a straight line, or a random-drunk walk. Is there any difference in the pairs selection you want to calculate the distance on?

Comment: @user3184950 I'm interested in adjacent pairs of points in 2 dimensions, regardless of distance between those points.  For 10 points on a straight line, I would get 9 distances.  If those 10 points are randomly scattered on a 2D grid, and no line would connect more than two points, then each point could consider every other point as a neighbor.

Comment: My gut feeling, is that the algorithm to check if points are on a straight line, won't be cheap, and can explode as the number of points grow. I can't think of anything smarter than just check all lines... Right?

Comment: @user3184950 I thought the same thing, hence my asking if anyone knows a more efficient way to address the problem beyond a brute force check of point triplets for collinearity.

Comment: http://www.bowdoin.edu/~ltoma/teaching/cs3250-CompGeom/spring17/Lectures/ex-collineartriplets.pdf Algorithm 2 seems easy to implement, hopefully fast enough for your data set

Comment: @ChrisM-B Algorithm 2 seems like the way to go as what I was thinking of offhand anyway though I would have suggested a hash table so, I'm more of a fan of Algorthm 4. That seems like the best you can do really unless you have additional information: IE: The colinear lines are always vertical or horizonal on an integer grid, in which case you only need to create X/Y lookup tables. Allowing for O(N) performance. Or perhaps co linear points appear only within clusters. I think it's a O(N^2) problem either way unless a property of your specific data allows you to do something fancy.

Comment: Hmmm one possibility is _maybe_ there is something you can do with a minimum spanning tree or delaunary triangulation that could improve that.

Comment: @Nuclearman I'm currently leaning toward Algorithm 4 too.  I don't have much experience with decision trees in Python, so I'm unsure how they could be utilized here.